# Using fields of temporary tables for insert

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I want to move all fields from a temporary table into another table, but my statement doesn't seem to be working. How can I select some fields after generating my temporary table to be used in an insert statement.

This is my code which generates a temp table, it works:

```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS(SELECT ca.catref AS cx_ref, c.name AS code_name, ca.title, ca.keywords, ca.cat1, ca.cat2, ca.cat3, ca.active, ca.moderated,
FROM table ca
JOIN anothertable c ON c.prefix = LEFT( ca.catref, 3 ))
```

This is my code which I call straight after, it references the temp table, but does not seem to work...

```
> INSERT INTO mytable (catref, cartoonist, title, keywords, cat1, cat2, cat3, active, moderated, source_db)
SELECT catref, code_name, title, keywords, cat1, cat2, cat3, active, moderated, source_db from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in the first query (create temporary), after `ca.moderate`, remove the coma...`ca.moderated,`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS(
SELECT ca.catref AS cx_ref, c.name AS code_name, 
ca.title, ca.keywords, ca.cat1, ca.cat2, ca.cat3,
ca.active, ca.moderated
FROM table ca
JOIN anothertable c ON c.prefix = LEFT( ca.catref, 3 ))
```

to insert try this:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` 
(catref, cartoonist, title, keywords, cat1, cat2, cat3, active, moderated, source_db) 
SELECT * 
from `table2`
```